# NSKeyedArchiver cannot archive arrays

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsdata

I am trying to develop a Cydia tweak, but now I have some problems.

I want to copy an NSMutableArray, so I use:

```
myArray = %orig;
NSMutableArray* myArray2;
myArray2 = myArray;
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: myArray2];
```

(The original function returned an NSMutableArray, so I use myArray = %orig; to get it)

However, seems the archivedDataWithRootObject doesn't work, it always causes my device crash.

So, is there any limit for archivedDataWithRootObject ? I don't know whether the original NSMutableArray is encoded or not. Can I use archivedDataWithRootObject for a encoded NSMutableArra?

Thanks for any suggestions and replies

Comment: Can you please provide a crash log? When an ObjC app dumps core it often prints out the call stack. I'd be good to see which function crashed. You can even use gdb to retrieve this and look at the backtrace.

Comment: Seems I cannot get them, because the whole iOS got crashed (respring), I cannot found a crash report in xcode.

Comment: I get the log now. It says "-[UIKBTree encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe8cdbe0"

Comment: That is a method from the NSCoding protocol `encodeWithCoder:`, that I said you must implement to be able to archive your data with NSKeyedArchiver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this line of code in your code :

> myArray = %orig;

And I can't see why you are doing this :

> NSMutableArray* myArray2;
>   myArray2 = myArray;

If you got an NSArray or an NSMutableArray you will be able to encode it directly with the that line of code :

```
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: myArray2];
```

BUT (there is always as but...)
What is store in your `NSArray`?
If you got `custom object` they must implement the NSCoding protocol to be able to participate in the Archiving dance.

AND finally you are saying :

> I want to copy an NSMutableArray, so I use:

If you just want to copy the `NSMutableArray` you can do this :

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:anArray];
```

---

I still don't get the `%` sign there.
If you need to add new object to it, why not just go simple, like create new object. If it's your own object you have 2 choice:
1st you implement the NSCopying protocol on those object an make them behave like you want, or
2nd choice : if the array contain one type of object you can create a Class method for those object that is like this : `newObjectWithArray:(* NSArray)theArray` and in that method you `alloc` `init` object that you initialize to the value of the receiving objet.

Comment: or even `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:anArray]`.

Comment: yes, but I like to avoid autoreleased object unless they are needed.

Comment: I use myArray = %orig; to get original array in iOS which the function returned. I tried to create a NSMutableArray with some int in the same custom object, but I can use NSKeyedArchiver to archive them. I will try [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:anArray];. :)

Comment: VinceBurn: he didn't state that, bur he is using Theos with the Logos language. It's not a standard, just a convenience framework. However, you're right that all methods contained in the array must respond to NSCoding methods.

Comment: No preblem. Btw I **do** like to avoid these non-standard frameworks. Lot of devs asked me why I don't use Theos <-- that's why.

Comment: OK, now I am using NSMutableArray *myNewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray copyItems:YES];  After that, creating a new object with [myNewArray objectAtIndex:0]; Finally [oldArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:];
 and it works now, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Hiraku double check if your newly copied items are just pointer copy or deep copy, if you want deep copy your item will need to implement the NSCopying protocol.